# Bind Angular Mat Paginator with back-end API JSON

Tags: angular, api, frontend, paginator

In my application I have a Spring REST Controller which exposes data in a JSON format, these data are already provided in a paginated format; in my Angular front-end I have declared a mat-paginator component to achive incoming data from the back-end but, for what I've understood until now, the mat-paginator handles the page format on its own (for example if I declare an array of 20 mock elements and set the mat-paginator page to 10 elements, Angular provides to handle the page count to the value of '2'), but I would to make this thing compatible with the back-end already provided page format without customize it even in the front-end. Is it possible to do that? Or do I need to pass the entire list of element in unpaged format in order to make the page directly in the front-end? This is the code of a page result from the back-end:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 89461,
      "name": "eu",
      "address": "73258 South Fairbanks Ct.",
      "tel_number": 330362914,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          44.92497,
          36.1748
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-18"
    },
    {
      "id": 99459,
      "name": "montes",
      "address": "28683 South Nauru Way",
      "tel_number": 328650809,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          34.26616,
          60.14567
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-18"
    },
    {
      "id": 13366,
      "name": "massa",
      "address": "20549 East Liberia Blvd.",
      "tel_number": 333236540,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.24598,
          38.3594
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-19"
    },
    {
      "id": 31927,
      "name": "tempor",
      "address": "48262 South Barbados Ct.",
      "tel_number": 327365240,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          42.17593,
          45.67655
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-19"
    },
    {
      "id": 16455,
      "name": "vehicula",
      "address": "63846 West Costa Rica Way",
      "tel_number": 333771974,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          50.84762,
          -3.74278
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-19"
    },
    {
      "id": 4068,
      "name": "elementum",
      "address": "39129  Henderson Blvd.",
      "tel_number": 333345108,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          17.93082,
          17.60466
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-20"
    },
    {
      "id": 39076,
      "name": "eros",
      "address": "75697 East Greece St.",
      "tel_number": 333710853,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          35.36623,
          15.51502
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-20"
    },
    {
      "id": 58449,
      "name": "sit",
      "address": "69309 East Aruba St.",
      "tel_number": 332365281,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          16.37542,
          21.24491
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-21"
    },
    {
      "id": 17085,
      "name": "magna",
      "address": "82350 West Falkland Islands (Malvinas) Ln.",
      "tel_number": 333290644,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          50.665,
          12.32584
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-21"
    },
    {
      "id": 11438,
      "name": "massa",
      "address": "54294  Billings St.",
      "tel_number": 331961026,
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          52.1453,
          43.26645
        ]
      },
      "creation_date": "2010-11-21"
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "unsorted": true,
      "sorted": false,
      "empty": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "last": false,
  "totalPages": 853,
  "totalElements": 8522,
  "sort": {
    "unsorted": true,
    "sorted": false,
    "empty": true
  },
  "number": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "numberOfElements": 10,
  "first": true,
  "empty": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'll have to create your own wrapper component to adapt the material table / paginator to your needs. It is simply not the frameworks job to handle any incoming data format e.g. spring. Maybe there is a npm package out there already doing it but the angular material framework will certainly not do it without any wrapping.

Edit: This obviously will only be the case if you wan't to paginate on your backend. If you fetch the whole list there shouldn't be any problem at all.